# Accessing array of pointers vs accessing pointer with multiple 'elements'?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, dereference

Hi I am new to C and am trying to understand the nuance between pointers and arrays. Specifically I don't understand what fundamentally distinguishes the following two objects:

```
int *obj1[N];
int *obj2;
obj2 = malloc(N*sizeof(int))
```

Both objects provide me essentially an array of pointers but I would reference them differently to retrieve the values they point to:

```
val1 = *obj1[i];
val2 = obj2[i];
```

I consider both of them in end effect 'arrays of pointers' (though I understand the use of the word 'array' for the obj2 is not technically correct), however obj2 seems to implicitly recognize that I want the value without the need to dereference with * while obj1 doesn't. Could someone clarify for me the structural difference between these two objects which leads to the above difference in referencing their values?

Comment: The old [clockwise/spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) might help you parsing those declarations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This declaration

```
int *obj1[N];
```

indeed declares an array of objects of the pointer type `int *`.

This declaration

```
int *obj2;
```

declares an object of the type `int *` and in the next statement

```
obj2 = malloc(N*sizeof(int));
```

there is allocated memory for an array of N elements of the type `int`.

So in this lines

```
val1 = *obj1[i];
val2 = obj2[i];
```

that for clarity are better to rewrite like

```
int val1 = *obj1[i];
int val2 = obj2[i];
```

you get objects of the type `int`. In the first line the expression `obj1[i]` yields an object of the type `int *` because `obj1` is an array of pointer. So to get the pointed object of the type `int` you need to dereference the pointer expression `obj1[i]`. In the second line the expression `obj2[i]` yields an object of the type `int` because there was allocated an array of integers.

If you want to allocate an array of pointers of the type `int *` you have to write

```
int **obj2 = malloc(N*sizeof(int *));
```

In this case to access elements of the both arrays you can write

```
int val1 = *obj1[i];
int val2 = *obj2[i];
```

Pay attention to that in this expression `obj1[i]` the array designator `obj1` is implicitly converted to a pointer of the type `int **` to its first element. So the both expressions `obj1[i]` and `obj2[i]` are equivalently evaluated. Also the both expressions `*obj1[i]` and `*obj2[i]` are equivalent to `obj1[i][0]` and `obj2[i][0]`.

On the other hand, you could also write for example

```
int **obj3 = obj1;  // the array is implicitly converted to pointer
//...
int val3 = *obj3[i];
```

Bear in mind that according to the C Standard (6.5.2.1 Array subscripting)

> 2 A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets []
> is a subscripted designation of an element of an array object. The
> definition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is identical to
> (*((E1)+(E2))). Because of the conversion rules that apply to the
> binary + operator, if E1 is an array object (equivalently, a pointer
> to the initial element of an array object) and E2 is an integer,
> E1[E2] designates the E2-th element of E1 (counting from zero)

Comment: So it seems to me that the square brackets always implicitly dereference the pointer just as they implicitly define a double pointer (as you pointed out). Therefore, anytime I have a pointer that points to an array of ints I never have to dereference the pointer object to get at the array so long as square brackets follow?

Comment: @hijit An expression like this p[i] where p is a pointer or an array is evaluated like *( p + i ). In case when p is an array then it is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element. If you have for example int a[] = { 1, 2, 3 }; int *p = a;  then the both expressions *p and *a are equivalent to p[0] and a[0].

Comment: great, thanks for the explanation, that clarifies things nicely.

Answer (score 1):

The first is an array of `int*`, pointers to `int`, supposedly allocated locally (on the stack). They do not point at any valid data yet.

The second is an array of `int` allocated dynamically (on the heap). It does not contain any valid values yet.

> Both objects provide me essentially an array of pointers

No, see above.

> but I would reference them differently

Yeah you will have to since they are different data types used for different purposes.

> I consider both of them in end effect 'arrays of pointers'

Again, this is wrong.

To dynamically allocate an array of pointers similar to `int *obj1[N];`, you have to do this:

```
int** ptrptr = malloc(n * sizeof *ptr);
```

Comment: [What gets allocated on the stack and the heap?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/277536)